# Are users less likely to engage in a site where the content they are posting take some time to write?

Tags: user-behavior

I'm building a site where users will be able to post tutorials (I guess they are not going to be very long).

This is how the submit form will look like (I will style it of course, and add a save as a draft check box).

[image]

It only has 3 steps but the content part will quite long (imagine all the steps of a tutorial).

I was wondering if users are less likely to engage in a site where the thing they are posting is quite long?

Comment: Not quite sure what are you asking here. If the user is interested in publishing their tutorial the length of it is up to them. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Give incentive like points/karma. But a very important thing, make sure the submit button works even after 2 hours. The worst part would be to lose everything that was written down.

Comment: Check out Snapguide for iOS for some helpful UX research in this space.

Answer (score 3):

Disregarding the user motivation in your use case, even motivated users tend to like the *appearance* of things taking less of an effort. One way to achieve this in your case is to make the submissing a step-by-step process with steps very short.

For example:

Instead of one page that asks you to fill out all the information and images, split them up into smaller portions like:

1. Enter your headline and topic
2. *Repeat:* Describe **one step** of the tutorial, upload image for this step
3. Review

Comment: Then there would be no way of changing the title as the content is created.  Some people start with the title, while other only work it out (or change it) while they write the body.  So separating them may frustrate some people.

Comment: Why would there be no way to change the title, you just go to the top, where the title would be and change it.

Comment: Or go back a step to revise the title. Either way I think most people might have a rough idea of an title for the tutorial they are going to write.

Comment: I just don't see why you couldn't display all the steps in a list on the same page as you go along.

Comment: Well, my point being that the less steps you see the less you are aware of that you still have a long way to go, and thus the more easy it is on the user to fill out all of the tutorial texts and steps.